# Recover lost volume group in hp ux 11 v2

Tags: lvm, hp-ux, disk-volume

The disk containing operating system (vg00) has failed. I tried to install the operating system on a new disk and I want to restore other volume group (vg01 and vg02) on two disks that contain data.